# Cursor for WebService is closed

Tags: java, oracle, cursor, oracle10g

Does someone know if I can do this: (it's a sketch from the SP)

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE cursor_values(
   p_cur_out OUT sys_refcursor
)
IS
   p_cur2 sys_refcursor;   

BEGIN
sql_query:='select c1,c2 from table';

open p_cur2 for sql_query;
LOOP
   -- Check data values
   -- Do actions whith the data
END LOOP;

   -- Reopen ref_cursor for output
   OPEN p_cur_out FOR sql_query;

END cursor_values;
```

When I execute an anonymous PL/SQL block (with SQL Developer) I get the cursor. But when I do it for a WebService in Java I get the error (in the Web Service)

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cursor is closed.
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CResultSetAccessor.getCursor(T4CResultSetAccessor.java:329)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.ResultSetAccessor.getObject(ResultSetAccessor.java:85)
```

I know the Web Service works fine. If I don't open the Cursor, works fine, but I need see the data.

Some help please, regards!

Comment: Please post relevant java code.

Comment: I think the java code is not necessary, because I'm sure it works if I do not fetch  the cursor p_cur2. If I just make the query and open the p_cur_out it works well. This is a problem with the cursor and de open or close features. :)